# How to display a specific element of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, bitcoin

I am using the [MtGOX API v2 example PHP code](https://github.com/pathaksa/MtGox-PHP-API-V2) to find the current price for Bitcoin. My code excerpt looks something like this:

```
<?php
$result = $mtGoxClient->getTicker();
?>

<pre>
    <?php print_r($result);?>
</pre>
```

I get the following outputted:

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
    [data] => Array
        (
            [high] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1056.90000
                    [value_int] => 105690000
                    [display] => $1,056.90000
                    [display_short] => $1,056.90
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [low] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 856.12300
                    [value_int] => 85612300
                    [display] => $856.12300
                    [display_short] => $856.12
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [avg] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 947.15239
                    [value_int] => 94715239
                    [display] => $947.15239
                    [display_short] => $947.15
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [vwap] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 943.98795
                    [value_int] => 94398795
                    [display] => $943.98795
                    [display_short] => $943.99
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [vol] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 23521.92105774
                    [value_int] => 2352192105774
                    [display] => 23,521.92105774Â BTC
                    [display_short] => 23,521.92Â BTC
                    [currency] => BTC
                )

            [last_local] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 922.50002
                    [value_int] => 92250002
                    [display] => $922.50002
                    [display_short] => $922.50
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [last_orig] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 922.50002
                    [value_int] => 92250002
                    [display] => $922.50002
                    [display_short] => $922.50
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [last_all] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 922.50002
                    [value_int] => 92250002
                    [display] => $922.50002
                    [display_short] => $922.50
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [last] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 922.50002
                    [value_int] => 92250002
                    [display] => $922.50002
                    [display_short] => $922.50
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [buy] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 922.00000
                    [value_int] => 92200000
                    [display] => $922.00000
                    [display_short] => $922.00
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [sell] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 922.50002
                    [value_int] => 92250002
                    [display] => $922.50002
                    [display_short] => $922.50
                    [currency] => USD
                )

            [item] => BTC
            [now] => 1386808426752872
        )

)
```

What PHP code would I use to just get the [data][high][display_short] (the one that reads $1,056.90)?

Comment: `$result['data']['high']['display_short']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the following:

```
$price = $result['data']['high']['display_short'];
```

I would highly recommend reading the [PHP.net documentation on arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php).